# Unable to parse optional routing parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

Currently I am following the official [Angular routing guide](https://angular.io/guide/router)

In this guide when we pass the optional params from /hero-detail.component.ts to /hero-list.component.ts in form of a back button, I am not able to read those parameters in the `ngOnInit` hook for hero-list.component.ts.

```js
gotoHeroes(hero: Hero) {
  let heroId = hero ? hero.id : null;
  // Pass along the hero id if available
  // so that the HeroList component can select that hero.
  // Include a junk 'foo' property for fun.
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
        this.selectedId = +params.get('id');
        return this.service.getHeroes();
      });
```

I have even downloaded their official example and tried to run it in my local browser I am getting default 0 value for the id.

Any idea why is it so?

Comment: Where is your code that subscribes to the `heroes$` observable? Or, the `async` pipe call that causes this to run? You seem to be missing something that actually makes this work. Did you follow the guide to completion?

Comment: can you try with `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');`

Comment: @R.Richards Yes i have followed the complete guide. Not only that i have downloaded their sample and run it without modification and the thing is not working.

Comment: FYI using snapshot its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code from official Angular guide doen's work is the redirection declared in the file **heroes-routing.module.ts**

```
const heroesRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heroes', redirectTo: '/superheroes' },
  { path: 'hero/:id', redirectTo: '/superhero/:id' },
  { path: 'superheroes',  component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: 'superhero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];
```

while the navigation path is constructed within the function in **hero-detail.component.ts**

```
gotoHeroes(hero: Hero) {
  let heroId = hero ? hero.id : null;
  // Pass along the hero id if available
  // so that the HeroList component can select that hero.
  // Include a junk 'foo' property for fun.
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
```

}

The constructed path is equal to:

```
http://localhost:4200/heroes;id=12;foo=foo
```

It clearly sets up **'/heroes'** (and not **'/superheroes'**) so the redirection takes place. Meanwhile, the remaining **";id=12;foo=foo"** (value 12 is provided as an example, it can be any ID of the superhero) is dropped from the URL as it is not recognized by the **Route.redirectTo** as parameter - contrary to the **:id** which is explicitly transfered in case of the redirection to the details of a superhero.

The solution is to avoid the redirection by replacing the path to navigate:

```
    this.router.navigate(['/superheroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
```

Comment: What if we having optional param in middle of URL not at last?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have hyphens(-) in the query params. Please retrieve the values using 
    below syntax.

Example url : `http://example.com/?query-type=test`

```
 this.params = _router.routerState.snapshot.root.queryParams;
 var queryparams = this.params['query-type']
```